# Figures Taking Up too much space

Tags: spacing, floats

I have two small figures that take up an entire page.  How can I reduce the space between/after the figures so that I can start the next section on the same page?

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{...}
    \caption{...}
    \label{fig:figure4}
        \end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{...}
    \caption{...}
    \label{fig:figure5}
        \end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
\section{...}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may have to do with the way LaTeX handles Figures and text on the same space.
In particular, LaTeX will dedicate an entire page to figures if the minimum amount of text on a page cannot be met.

You can use the following three commands in your preamble (Note there may be better ways) to adjust this. I believe that these use the setspace package, I can't confirm this as I'm pulling the examples out of an old document.

```
% To be confirmed that it requires the setspace package, try with and without.
\usepackage{setspace}

% Let top 85% of a page contain a figure
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}

% Default amount of minimum text on page (Set to 10%)
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}

% Only place figures by themselves if they take up more than 75% of the page
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}
```

Hope this helps you but you may need to experiment.
In addition, there are the obvious usual caveats when you are changing default behaviour that you are responsible etc.